# With multiple objects selected, how can I tell which keyframes in the timeline relate to which object?

Tags: animation, interface

If I have everything selected and can see all my keyframes in timeline, how do I easily identify which keyframe relates to which 3D object?

I often have a "what the heck does that keyframe do to what object?" moment once I've got a good few on the timeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have noticed, the timeline is good for

- scrubbing,
- playback settings and options and
- manipulating the keyframes of a single or very few objects.

You need to switch to another animation editor type: the [dopesheet](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/dope_sheet/introduction.html) or the [graph editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/graph_editor/introduction.html).

[image: switch to dopesheet]

> The Dope Sheet gives the animator a birds-eye-view of the keyframes inside the scene.

[image: dopesheet]

The dopesheet can show

- the object's name (1),
- the object's action (2) (if you have set keyframes you will have exactly one action)
- the keyframe groups name (3) (keyframes for the same object are groups)
- the names of the individual animation curves (fcurves) (4)

You can also toggle the *Only Selected* option (5), which will only show the keyframes for the selected objects.

The dopesheet provides you with a good overview for your keyframes. It is not only possible to manipulate the time property of keyframes (on which frame they are set) but also their values.

[image: channel values]
<sup>*Click to enlarge.*</sup>

If you wish to view the keyframes as individual curves or have finer control over their handles, you can switch to the *graph editor*.

Comment: also the markers could help to know when a certain action happes, M to create, ctrl M to rename, X to delete

Comment: A ha! Thank you Leander.

So, to add a little info. Use the Dopesheet. Click on the marker I want to identify then Shift-MouseWheel for vertical scroll in the dopesheet and find the corresponding (also highlighted) keyframe component - then look to the left int he dopesheet list to see *what* the item is.

Many thanks! Much appreciated.